# Cannot get local html file to talk to local express Node.js server. Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

I'm new to web design and am trying to create and a simple local server and a local client. I fear I have fallen down the rabbit hole as I'm going round in circles.

I have made a simple Express node.js server:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var port = 3000;

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on port: " + port);
});
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req);
    res.send('Get request received at "/"');
});

app.post('/quotes', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req);
    // do something

});
```

and I have a javascript client:

```
const url = "http://localhost/3000";
fetch(url)

.then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(function(response) {

        let data = response.results;
        console.log(data);
        //do something
    })

.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

called from an index.html file.

When I type http://localhost:3000 into my (chrome) browser I get

> 'Get request received at "/"'

displayed in the browser and a very long req displayed in the node.js console just as I expect.

However when I load the index.html into the browser it doesn't work.

Originally the index.html file was in a different directory to the node.js server and I got the error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

So I moved it into the same directory as the node.js server and now get this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>   in the browser console and no output in the node console.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I needed to enable cors on my server. npm install cors and this answer solved my problem.
[How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)

Answer (score 0):

I would replace

`const url = "http://localhost/3000";`

with `const url = "http://localhost:3000";`

Comment: That did not work, but it did get my old error back. Browser console now shows:  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.